# Rspec - post - MassAssignmentSecurity::Error

Tags: ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mass-assignment

I have few models: **User** and **Article**. User has_many articles and Article belongs to user.

I try to write test to check `Post` method (NOTE: i use locales in my application):

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ArticlesController do
  render_views

  before(:each) do
    @admin = FactoryGirl.create( :admin )
    @user  = FactoryGirl.create( :user )
  end

  describe "POST 'create'" do
    before(:each){ @article = FactoryGirl.create(:article) }

    describe "for signed-in admin" do
      before(:each){ test_sign_in( @admin ) }

      it "should create article" do
        expect do
          post :create, :locale => :en, :article => @article.attributes.merge( :content => "some" )
        end.should change( Article, :count ).by(1)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But i get such error:

```
1) ArticlesController POST 'create' for signed-in admin should create article
     ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error:
       Can't mass-assign protected attributes: id, user_id, created_at, updated_at
     Failure/Error: post :create, :locale => :en, :article => @article.attributes.merge( :content => "some" )
     # ./app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:15:in `create'
     # ./spec/controllers/articles_controller_spec.rb:106:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/controllers/articles_controller_spec.rb:105:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

How can i fix that?

My Factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "email#{n}@factory.com" }
    password  'qwerty'

    factory :admin do
      admin true
    end
  end

  factory :article do
    content 'text is here'
    user
  end
end
```

My controller:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter do
    redirect_to :root unless current_user && current_user.admin?
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new( params[:article] )

    if @article.save
      redirect_to articles_path
      flash[:success] = "It has been created!"
    else
      render 'new'                                                                       
    end
  end
end
```

Article model:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: articles
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  user_id    :integer
#  content    :text
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  attr_accessible :content

  validates :content,
              :presence => { :message => :presense_message },
              :length   => {
                             :maximum => 50000,
                             :message => :max_lenght_message
                           }
end
```

UPD: Application is here: https://github.com/Loremaster/Chirch_app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without testing your code directly I can't say for sure, but try changing

```
before(:each){ @article = FactoryGirl.create(:article) }
```

to

```
before(:each){ @article = FactoryGirl.build(:article, :user => @admin) }
```

so that you are giving the article an author as well as [not saving the article](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#using-factories) before you make the call to POST.  Also, this line should probably also go within your `describe "for signed-in admin"` block.

#### Edit

Your `MassAssignmentSecurity::Error`s will go away if you change your test code so that you `build` your `:article` *upfront* with all the necessary parameters as defined in [your factories](https://github.com/Loremaster/Chirch_app/blob/master/spec/factories.rb):

**spec/controllers/articles_controllers.spec**

```
describe "POST 'create'" do
  before(:each) do
    @article = FactoryGirl.build(:article, :user => @admin, :content => "some")
  end

describe "for non-signed users" do
  it "should deny access" do
    post :create, :locale => :en, :article => @article
    response.should redirect_to( root_path )
  end

  it "should not create article" do
    expect do
      post :create, :locale => :en, :article => @article
    end.should_not change( Article, :count )
  end
end

describe "for signed-in users" do
  before(:each){ test_sign_in( @user ) }

  it "should deny access" do
    post :create, :locale => :en, :article => @article
    response.should redirect_to( root_path )
  end

  it "should not create article" do
    expect do
      post :create, :locale => :en, :article => @article
    end.should_not change( Article, :count )
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried your solution and this changed nothing. I still have my error.

Comment: Got a Github repo you can share so people can test your code for themselves?

Comment: Yes, i have github account. Check my update in question, please.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! But i still have problem with admin. 

When i try that: `expect do post :create, :locale => :en, :article => @article.attributes.merge(:content => "some" ) end.should change( Article, :count ).by(1)` it shows: `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: id, user_id, created_at, updated_at`.

Comment: I tried that: `post :create, :locale => :en, :article => @article` and `post :create, :locale => :en, :articles => { :content => "some", :title => "text" }, :user_id => @admin.id`. Error is `count should have been changed by 1, but was changed by 0`.

Comment: As far as I can see, if you change your code to not use `attributes.merge`, you won't get the first `MassAssignmentSecurity::Error` you mentioned.  As for your second error, that's a separate problem: you will need to find some way to figure out what `controller.sign_in` in your `test_sign_in` method is doing.  I'm not familiar enough with Devise to help you there (perhaps you could pose it as a separate question on StackOverflow), but I believe the original problem in your question has been solved.